# UIStackView - arranged views are overlapping

Tags: swift, xcode, constraints, uistackview

I've been struggling for the past hours to add custom views to a UIStackView. The StackView is placed inside a UIScrollView, with constraints set to each margin of the ScrollView. Everything is design in a Storyboard.

Then in code I have the following for loop which should add my custom views to the stack:

```
for name in names {
    let initialChildProfile = ChildProfileView.loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: "ChildProfileView") as! ChildProfileView
    initialChildProfile.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: childrenStackOutlet.frame.size.width, height: initialChildProfile.frame.size.height)
    initialChildProfile.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    childrenStackOutlet.addArrangedSubview(initialChildProfile)
}
```

I've done this so many times before and everything went fine, but this time the custom views are overlapping each other. Only if I set the spacing to something larger than 0, I can actually see that is more than 1 view.

I tried setting the "translateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints" to false, I tried setting hardcoded values for the frame of the custom views, different constraints to the stack, even removed it from the scrollview. But nothing works.

PS I tried the few solutions I've seen online. Still nothing.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is autolayout

```
for name in names {
    let initialChildProfile = ChildProfileView.loadFromNibNamed(nibNamed: "ChildProfileView") as! ChildProfileView
    initialChildProfile.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    initialChildProfile.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: childrenStackOutlet.frame.size.width).isActive = true
    //initialChildProfile.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: self.view.frame.width - 50).isActive = true
    initialChildProfile.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

    childrenStackOutlet.addArrangedSubview(initialChildProfile)
}
```

Comment: You are right. Using your constraints I no longer have the problem, but I have to use both constraints, width and height. The issue now is that the custom views will have various heights depending on the content, so I can't really use the height value... Do you have any idea?

Comment: if your custom view has a various height you must remove heightAncher in my code and use autolayout in your customview after that the stack view height is dynamic depend on your customview height